# Soap WSDL com PHP dando erro

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
    try {

$client = new SoapClient("link.wsdl");
$function = "METADOPRINCIPAL";

$arguments =  array(

'METADOPRINCIPAL' => array(
     'Msg'     => array(
       'Transacao'     => array(
         'ME_DVW' => array(
           'INSTITUCAO'     => 'K2',
           'CURSO'       => $curso
         )
        )
     )




 ));
$options = array('location' => '"link.wsdl"');
$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

print_r($result);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Error! ";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();}
```

E estou tentando fazer um get simples dos parâmetros do método `METADOPRINCIPAL` mas está dando erro:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FieldTypes' property

Já tentei de várias formas de fazer essa conexão SOAP funcionar e não estou conseguindo, podem me ajudar?

Eu preciso passar apenas 2 parâmetros para obter retorno, mas pelo que parece preciso enviar o xml inteiro

```
'CURSO'       => $curso / 'INSTITUICAO'       => 'K2'
```